# Why export a class and a namespace with the same name?

Tags: typescript, namespaces

I found some code, written by someone who presumably knew what they were doing, where both a class and a namespace with the same names were exported from a module.  What could the purpose of this be?  Is this a common pattern in TypeScript?

This is essentially what I observed in the Typescript module:

```
export class A {
    constructor(arg: A.B) {

    }
} 

export namespace A {

    export interface B {
        C: number
    }
}
```

Comment: "*someone who presumably knew what they were doing*" - a dangerous presumption to make.

Comment: I guess they wanted the interface `B` to be hanging off the name `A` so that it looks like it "belongs" to the class `A`?  Without more context it's hard to say if this is a good or bad approach for the use case

Answer (score 1):

This is one of senarios which need the structure. Let's say there is your own library or app like this.

```
- src
  - views
    ListView.ts
    PinnedListView.ts
- test
  App.ts
```

Below example is how your files *can* be like before/after you use the structure.

#### Before

```
// ListView.ts

class ListView<A extends Adapter> {
  protected adapter?: A;
  ...
  setAdapter(adapter: A) {
    ...
  }
}

export abstract class Adapter {
  abstract id(pos: number): number;
}

export default ListView;
```

```
// PinnedListView.ts

import ListView, {Adapter} from "./ListView";

class PinnedListView<A extends PinnedListViewAdapter> extends ListView<A> {
  ...
}

export abstract class PinnedListViewAdapter extends Adapter {
  abstract shouldPin(pos: number): boolean;
}

export default PinnedListView;
```

```
// App.ts

// let's say you use path alias
import PinnedListView, {PinnedListViewAdapter} from "views/PinnedListView";

class MyAdapter extends PinnedListViewAdapter {
  // your implementation
}

const pinnedListView = new PinnedListView();
const myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
pinnedListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

#### After

```
// ListView.ts

class ListView<A extends ListView.Adapter> {
  protected adapter?: A;
  ...
  setAdapter(adapter: A) {
    ...
  }
}

namespace ListView {
  export abstract class Adapter {
    abstract id(pos: number): number;
  }
}

export default ListView;
```

```
// PinnedListView.ts

import ListView from "./ListView";

class PinnedListView<A extends PinnedListView.Adapter> extends ListView<A> {
  ...
}

namespace PinnedListView {
  export abstract class Adapter extends ListView.Adapter {
    abstract shouldPin(pos: number): boolean;
  }
}

export default PinnedListView;
```

```
// App.ts

// let's say you use path alias
import PinnedListView from "views/PinnedListView";

class MyAdapter extends PinnedListView.Adapter {
  // your implementation
}

const pinnedListView = new PinnedListView();
const myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
pinnedListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Imagine when there are more classes that you want to name `Adapter` no matter what they function, this structure makes

- your app clean from codes to avoid naming collisions like prepending the name of consuming class in front of `Adapter`
- readers free from pain to remember what class an `Adapter` is for